# Deploy Active Directory and ADFS 2.0 in Azure Virtual Machine and integrate it with ACS

Tags: azure, adfs2.0, acs

Is it possible to use an Azure virtual machine as an Active Directory server with ADFS 2.0 and integrate it with ACS ?

Regards ,

James Roeiter

Comment: This is not really programming-related -> probably gets better responses at [Serverfault.com](http://Serverfault.com) where sysadmins hang out

Comment: Not necessarily because you manage all those stuff as a developer from Visual Studio and you need to know how to build the deployment package .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having AD server (with RMS also) in cloud is an ask which I have heard time to time from Azure users and it sure is a great addition to have it running in Windows Azure or any cloud. Various organization's IT is asking the same as well however As of now with current Windows Azure it is not possible.

A few might suggest that using Windows Azure VM Role however, I would say that there are concern over that as well do to persistence and other issues so I would say it is not possible with Windows Azure VM Role as well and there are other issues related with Active Directory product as well to run in Cloud scenarios.

If I answer it directly, I would say **as of now it is not supported and suggested scenario to have AD on Windows Azure** and will not work due to various reasons.

Comment: When dealing with persistance , whats the difference between Azure VM Role and regular server you host on your local server farm ? You need to deal with the same issues , no ? 
Or if there are specific issues with VM Role perhaps I can host other servers in different cloud companies solutions and manage my AD there ....

Comment: First of all Web and worker role have an architecture where basic code is running in machine however important data is persisted outside the VM. These machines are updated frequently with patches also. With VM role you are doing the same however there are issues when you need to update anything on these VM. There is limitation with Diff VM. Top of that the VM role is still in BETA and we don't suggest to use as of now.

Answer (score 1):

You can now install AD on Azure in a persistent state.  Its still preview but I have just got an standalone AD on a separate network on Azure.  I haven't finished wiring up ADFS and ACS but given a little time to get my head around it and I will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to put your AD server in Azure? If it just for testing - you can. However the current state of Windows Azure only allows you to have a VM Role, which is Stateless. That means, you may prepare your VM with the AD, all configured for ACS and fill up with users. However you can't rely on any changes to be persisted (including password changed, user edits). VM Role is stateless, which means you will lose your changes once the role is recycled or rebooted, or healed.

So the final answer for the current Windows Azure offering would be - don't do that now, unless you want to just play around and see if it works.

** EDIT **

I am not an AD expert, what I managed to do and have an "in-house-virtualized" lab is to have ADFS on VM integrated with ACS. Another VM running Windows 7, which is domain joined to my AD. Then a web deployed application which leverage ACS with ADFS integration. Everything works fine.

As for storing AD data on external persistent storage -  I don't know if it is possible, and how to configure that (already told you I am not AD expert). But if you know how to configure the storage for AD, and if you can store it in an SQL Azure, it is worth to give it a try.

And, finally, as Sandrino mentioned read the provided link to ZDNet's blog post, which has information you might find helpful.

Comment: To continue on astaykov's answer, it might be interesting to wait for Windows Azure Active Directory: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-finally-goes-public-with-windows-azure-active-directory-details/12795

Comment: The main reason is I want a good solid token provider (SAML) which is now available in ADFS 2.0 ... 
Access Control Service only allows me to use external authentication providers (Facebook,Windows Live etc) .
I saw I can integrate ASP.NET membership provider with ACS as well , but that requires me develop my own STS. 
Cant I use Active direcotry on one of my VMS but use that Actie Direcotry storage on external persistant storage ?

Comment: You don't have to develop your own STS. You can use the popular identityserver: http://identityserver.codeplex.com/

Comment: @sandrino - IdentityServer is good point, however it is STS, not Identity Provider. There is difference. You can't (easily) manage identities in IdentityServer

Comment: I checked it for several days . 
I have the following points on my mind , please correct me if I am wrong . 
1.Identity Server , no matter how much skilled the guy that wrote it is , is a one man show , not a mature prodcut that you will acctually take for your production system/web site .
2.I checked it and its hard to config .
3.WHY TO USE IT if I can use ADFS instead ?!!!
4.Why to use it if I can install something like OpenAM or WSO 2 instead ?!

Azure does not give enough powerful identity managemenet tools ,smoething that Amazon does.
Also , that stateless virtual machine mode - HARD!

Comment: @astaykov -- I have no problem to use regular ASP.NET membership provider with Identity Server - the problem is that its not really a product ... its some cool code plex project one guy developed ...
Thats the problem with .NET , the open source community is not powerful enough , when you go higher then the syntax /lunguage scope to the system architecture scope , you find out there so many things missing :( :( :(

Comment: Just to note: IdentityServer is an IP - it has it's own identity store. A reason to use it instead of ADFS is a) it's not locked down like ADFS so can be extended b) you can authenticate against something other than AD i.e. a SQL DB.

Comment: @nzpcmad, follow this thread, it might change your vision of IdentityServer: http://identityserver.codeplex.com/discussions/351086

Comment: @astaykov - I completely agree with Dominick. It's an STS NOT an Identity Manager. You have exactly the same "problem" with ADFS. A STS authenticates against a credential store. It does not provision the users in the credential store.