# Windows Azure Active Directory Rights Management

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-roles, rights-management, azure-active-directory

See this link

[Active Directory Rights Management Services SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh535290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

*The Active Directory Rights Management Services SDK 2.0 platform enables developers to build applications that leverage Active Directory Rights Management Services (AD RMS) or Windows Azure Active Directory Rights Management (AADRMS) to provide information protection.*

Trying to learn more about "Windows Azure Active Directory Rights Management (AADRMS)".
It has a name AADRMS but searching on it only brings back the link above.

I know more than one question but all about Azure RMS.
Can the server components be hosted in an Azure Web Role?  Virtual Server?
Under Azure does Authentication come from ACS (via Active Directory Federation Service)?

I see where Office 365 Developers Site can use ACS.
That is not at all my question.
Our service does not author or alter any content.
We have existing files that would like the level of security offered by RMS.

If the desktop app does not support RMS could we secure the XPS rendition with RMS?

This question states NO to my question (host RMS in Azure).
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816075/deploy-active-directory-and-adfs-2-0-in-azure-virtual-machine-and-integrate-it-w)
With RMS 2.0(.1) and ACS has that changed?

If the answer is NO nothing has changed please let me know and I will delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the name is actually Azure Active Rights Directory Management (AAD RM). I will get this fixed. AAD RM today ships as part of Office 365. You can get more details about this here: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj585016.aspx

The AD RMS SDK 2.1 RC released few days ago, is available at: https://connect.microsoft.com/site1170/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=48166. (If you haven’t registered on Microsoft Connect, then: Go to connect.microsoft.com, sign in with your Microsoft Account > Directory> Search for Rights Management Services > Join)

You can also write your questions at http://connect.microsoft.com/site1170/feedback. The RMS team monitors these feedbacks daily and can answer your questions there.

Or, you can email directly at askIPTeam@microsoft.com